# Class Member Access on Instantiation

Tags: php, function, class, instantiation, language-features

In PHP 5.4, I believe something like this is valid:

```
echo ( new DateTime( '2014-04-05 10:36am' ))->format( 'Y-m-d g:ia' );
```

On PHP 5.3, I currently do something like this:

```
$date = new DateTime( '2014-04-05 10:36am' );
echo $date->format( 'Y-m-d g:ia' );
```

Any way to combine those two lines into a single line in PHP 5.3 (and I don't mean by concatenating the lines)?  Or will I have to upgrade to >=5.4 to have that option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will I have to upgrade to >=5.4 to have that option?

**Yes.** You need to upgrade to PHP 5.4 to do that.

That was a [**new feature**](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) introduced on PHP 5.4 actually..
**Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().**

---

If you try doing that on PHP versions less than **5.4** , you will run into this error.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR, expecting ','
>   or ';'

Comment: I knew it was a new feature implemented in 5.4, just wasn't sure if there was a way to "fake it" in the meantime.. thanks!

Comment: Yeah but it can't be put up in one statement.. :)