# Why isn't this working on some installations? (Dispatcher::Instance())->someFunction();

Tags: php

I often use something like `(Dispatcher::Instance())->someFunction();` if I only need a function of an object once, so I don't have to "waste" a new variable.

Turns out this does not seem to work on some PHP (PHP5?) installations aborting with:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ';'
```

I know, I can circumvent this by using a variable, but I want to understand why there is an error. Couldn't find anything in the release notes. Also I am not sure what to search for. Can somebody help?

Comment: In such an instance can you not just remove the `()` and just do `Dispatcher::Instance()->someFunction();`? I could see if you were doing `(new Instance())->someMethod()`, then you need the `()` wrappers.

Comment: Learned something new.

Comment: look here https://3v4l.org/6kePK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "Class Member Access on Instantiation" and was included with the release of PHP v5.4.0. ([*see release notes*](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.4.0))

It allows the instantiation of the class as displayed with your example (*without having to assign it to a variable*):

```
(Dispatcher::Instance())->someFunction();
```

Ideally, anywhere you look throughout the Stack Exchange network, it seems more efficient to `static`'ally call these methods.

<sup>[*Ref #1*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24654216/2518525), [*Ref #2*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/290057/94837), [*Ref #3*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22890622/2518525)*....etc. Just search for -> "Class member access on instantiation "*</sup>

To answer your question, this error is thrown has to do with this functionality not being present prior to `php >= 5.4`, hence the "requirement" for the variable/instantiation to be closed off `;` as a definition.

---

I recommend you take this piece of advice with you before you make any decisions to do this as you currently are:

> *Generally speaking, you should use static methods when the method in
>   question has both nothing to do with any state that is not passed in
>   as an argument to it and has more to do with the abstract notion of
>   the class involved, rather than with a concrete instance of one. That
>   is, the function relates to the idea of the thing, rather than to the
>   thing, itself.*

[*Source: Reddit - When is it appropriate to use static methods over class member access on instantiation and vice versa?*](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/3e2kxw/when_is_it_appropriate_to_use_static_methods_over/?st=izi1jt0p&sh=7c65d01e)

Comment: This seems to go in the right direction. Still it's failing on my server with PHP 5.5.9, but I now have an idea what to serach for. Thank you.

Comment: @christian That's weird! And you've confirmed your version?